# Exponential Distribution Function

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

If $X\sim \text{Exp}(X)$  then for all positive $a$ and $b$, $P(X>a+b\mid X>a)=P(X>b).$ So given independent random variables $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$, $Y \sim\text{Exp}(\mu)$ we would like to know $P(Y>a+X\mid Y>a)$ with the intention of using this for probabilities that a gap between two order statistics is of a certain magnitude.

> So $P(Y>a+X\mid Y>a)=P(Y>X)$. Why is $P(Y>X) = \mathbb{E}[\exp(\mu X)]= \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$? Is it because the above theorem is for fixed $a$, and $X$ "varies", meaning that we need to integrate and get an expectation value in the process?

I also think this will help show, given $Z\sim \text{Exp}(\nu)$, also independent, $P(Y>X\cap Z>X)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu+\nu}$. This is referring to the more general

$P(\bigcap_{k=1}^n\{X_k>a+b_k\} \mid \min(\{X_k\})>a)=P(\bigcap_{k=1}^n\{X_k>b_k\})$ which imples, by setting $b_k=X$ $\forall k$, that

$$P(\min(Y,Z)>a+X\mid \min(Y,Z)>a)=P(\{Y>a+X\}\cap\{Z>a+X\}\mid\min(Z,Y)>a)=P(\{Z>X\}\cap \{Y>X\})$$

Which provided the above expectation identity holds will give me the final expression

$$P(\min(Y,Z)>a+X\mid a<\min(Y,Z))=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda +\mu+\nu}$$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match MSE quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: Write the double integral giving the probability $P[Y>X]$, and you should then see that the first equality holds. A bit of computation then gives the second equality.

Comment: $\int _0^{\infty }\lambda  \text{Exp}[-\lambda  x]\left(\int _x^{\infty }\text{  }\mu  \text{Exp}[-\mu  y]dy\right) dx$ is the integral?

Comment: Yes to your first comment. Evaluating the inner integral gives the first equality (which is your second comment, I think). Then evaluating the outer integral gives the second equality.

Comment: You fix an $x$, if the outer integral is with respect to $x$. Then the inner integral is over all $y>x$; hence, from $x$ to $\infty$.

Comment: The limits were changed because I changed the order of the integration? Which should you integrate first if you fix $x$? I thought it would be $y$ so that the bounds would be $[0,x]$

Comment: @shilov Thanks for editing your question! It looks much better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now see that you wanted $\Pr(Y>X)$ rather than $\Pr(X>Y)$.  Below is what I posted originally, saying that one needs to construe "$X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$" as meaning $X$ has an exponential distribution with **expected value** $\lambda$, rather than that is means $X$ has an exponential distribution with **rate** $\lambda$.  But in order to get $\Pr(Y>X)=\lambda/(\lambda+\mu)$ rather than $\Pr(X>Y)=\lambda/(\lambda+\mu)$, one actually needs to do it the other way around.  So make the trivial changes in the argument originally posted here, replacing every $\lambda$ with $1/\lambda$ and similarly for $\mu$.  For the sake of completeness, I'll give the argument here:

If $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ then $\Pr(X>x) = e^{-\lambda x}$, So $\Pr(X>Y\mid Y)=e^{-\lambda Y}$.  The law of total probability tells us that $\Pr(Y>X)=\mathbb E(\Pr(Y>X\mid X))$.  So
$$
\mathbb E(\Pr(Y>X\mid X)) = \mathbb E(e^{-\mu X}) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu x} \Big(e^{-\lambda x}\,(\lambda\,dx)\Big) = \int_0^\infty e^{-(\lambda+\mu)x} \, \mu\,dx = \frac{\lambda}{\mu+\lambda}.
$$

**Original answer:**

This will answer part of what you're asking.  If $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ then $\Pr(X>x) = e^{-x/\lambda}$, So $\Pr(X>Y\mid Y)=e^{-Y/\lambda}$.  The law of total probability tells us that $\Pr(X>Y)=\mathbb E(\Pr(X>Y\mid Y))$.  So
$$
\mathbb E(\Pr(X>Y\mid Y)) = \mathbb E(e^{-Y/\lambda}) = \int_0^\infty e^{-y/\lambda}\Big(e^{-y/\mu}\,(dy/\mu)\Big) = \int_0^\infty e^{-y\left(\frac1\lambda+\frac1\mu\right)} \, \frac{dy}{\mu}
$$
$$
=\frac1\mu\cdot\frac{1}{\frac1\lambda+\frac1\mu} = \frac{\lambda}{\mu+\lambda}.
$$

(For this to be right, one must assume that "$X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$" means $X$ has an exponential distribution with **expected value** $\lambda$, rather than that is means $X$ has an exponential distribution with **rate** $\lambda$.)

Comment: So $\int_0^{\infty } \lambda  \exp (-\lambda  x) \int_x^{\infty } \mu  e^{-\mu  y} \, dy \, dx$ is not the correct way? It gives the answer more by coincidence?

Comment: I've just added to the answer, since I misread part of the question.

Comment: In a sense, both versions of the answer say the same thing.